# Strange behaviour in laravel routing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes

Consider the two following laravel routing directives (I am using laravel version 5.0.35, but I found the same behaviour in version 5.5):

```
    Route::get('/a/b', function(){return "One";});
     .
     .
     .
    Route::get('/a/b', function(){return "Two";});
```

I know they don't make much sense, but consider them.
Theoretically, the priority is that the first one would prevail over the second. But if you access the site with

`http://whatever.com/a/b`

the response is

> Two

I guess this happens because even if the real selected directive is the first, it happened that the second one **OVERWROTE** the first one with his return value.

My question is: Is this the intended behaviour? Because it may be obvious when you only have two lines in your routes file, but not when you have dozens of them, and you inadvertently could duplicate the same directive and think that the return value of the first one is the one to be returned.

Comment: The version of laravel is 5.0.35

Comment: 5.0.x ... what is x ? the exact version

Comment: @lagbox I updated the question and comment , the version is 5.0.35

Answer (score 3):

**Is this the intended behavior?**

Yes. Whenever you create a route with the same name, when the project load, it replaces the last one on the route file([LIFO method](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/l/lifo.asp)). When we add some changes on project, we used to run `composer dump-autoload; php artisan route:clear`. with all these commands it dumps all the previous routes and loads new routes to application memory.

When I was doing a project I had the same issue. While inspecting I got the repeating route name issue. once fixed all runs smoothly.

check this as well  - [Multiple routes with same URL, but different names](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/multiple-routes-with-same-url-but-different-names)

Comment: `cache:clear` doesn't have to do with route caching, nor would dumping the autoload

Comment: @lagbox yeah. forgot that. didn't notice when copping from the terminal. Thanks btw

Comment: I don't think route caching has anything to do with my issue. Also, isn't still a bit confusing that the last line in your route file may be the real one used, perverting the "first rule found, first rule used"?

Comment: a route is an URL. which run in the browser. The application keeps remembering those only. The same name will get replace obviously.

Comment: @Amarnasan that would be when there are multiple routes that could match ... what Abdulia Nilam is saying is there is only 1 route registered in the end, not 2  ... i understand the confusion with that, as the first come first served is correct, but in this case there is only 1 actually registered in the collection at the end